# Excel user form combobox once submitted output to excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I am relatively new to the whole VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated...
I am having issues with getting my Combobox on my form (once you hit the submit button) to input the information to my excel spreadsheet in a specific column which would move down a row each time a new record is entered.

Please see my code below and If you need any further information please ask away :)  Many Thanks in advance Paula

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim EorP As String
    Dim ComboStaus As ComboBox

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("BS Personal Data")

    'find first empty row in spreadsheet
    irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    EorP = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    Combo = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    'copy the data to the spreadsheet

    With ws
        .Cells(irow, 1).Value = Me.txtmanager.Value
        .Cells(irow, 2).Value = Me.txtdivision.Value
        .Cells(irow, 3).Value = Me.txtlocation.Value
        .Cells(irow, 4).Value = Me.txtsystemname.Value
        .Cells(irow, 9).Value = Me.Txtpurpose.Value
        .Cells(irow, 10).Value = Me.txtaccess.Value
        .Cells(irow, 11).Value = Me.txtdatecompleted.Value
    End With

    'clear the data
    Me.txtmanager.Value = ""
    Me.txtdivision.Value = ""
    Me.txtlocation.Value = ""
    Me.txtsystemname.Value = ""
    Me.Txtpurpose.Value = ""
    Me.txtaccess.Value = ""
    Me.txtdatecompleted.Value = ""

    'set option button to input data based on type of information to column 5
    With ws
        If OptElectronic Then
            .Cells(EorP, 5).Value = "Electronic"
        Else
            .Cells(EorP, 5).Value = "PaperBased"
        End If
    End With

    'set option button to input data based on personal data into column 7
    With ws
        If PersonalYes Then
            .Cells(EorP, 7).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            .Cells(EorP, 7).Value = "No"
        End If
    End With

    'set option button to input data based on privacy notes into column 8
    With ws
        If PrivacyYes Then
            .Cells(EorP, 8).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            .Cells(EorP, 8).Value = "No"
        End If
    End With

End Sub

'combo button setup
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ComboStatus.Clear
    With ComboStatus  'this loads the combo
        .AddItem ""
        .AddItem "Live"
        .AddItem "Archived"
        .AddItem "zzz"
    End With

End Sub

'close button on the form
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code please?

Comment: It brings up the drop down for my combo box and you can select one from the list but once you hit submit on the form the information doesnt enter into my spreadsheet

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your code where you're referring to the `ComboBox` to fill the sheet. What is the name of the `ComboBox`?

Comment: That could be what i'm missing then :S its named ComboStatus

Comment: You probably need to add `.Cells(irow, 12).Value = Me.ComboStatus.Value` to where you're adding the data into the sheet?

Comment: I keep getting an error message with that saying method or data member not found... and it highlights my first row Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Comment: If a combo box named ```ComboStatus``` exists on the form then it should  be possible to call ```Clear``` on it. Do you have ```Option Explicit``` at the very beginning of the user form code module?

Comment: I've just added that in now...at the very top of my code however I still cant get the row of code for adding to the excel sheet to work :S